# Why EOSIO going to discard eosiocpp tool?

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.system, eosio.cdt

EOSIO introduced new eosio.cdt tool for contract development and there is  many changes related to typedefs in this tool.

- Is eosio.cdt official by eos ? asking this because they have not 
  mentioned the changes in typedefs on git repo.
- My question is when we are developing which typedefs should we use in our 
  code?

Comment: CDT is the official toolkit

Comment: Then why there is still not any changes in contract(in repo) regarding new typedefs?

Comment: Are you looking the new new contract repo as well? https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts